# Is TPngImage.Destroy() called when TPngImage goes out of scope if TPngImage.Free() is not called

Tags: delphi, graphics, png

I have a function that takes a TPicture as a parameter and returns a TPngImage. To preserve the original image I create a TPngImage and copy the TPicture to the TPngImage, apply the effect and return the TPngImage. As so.

```
function Effect( const Value : TPicture ) : TPngImage;
  var
    AnImage : TPngImage;

  begin
    if( Value.Graphic is TPngImage ) then
      begin
        AnImage := TPngImage.Create();
        AnImage.Assign( TPngImage( Value ) );
        //Apply effect
        Result := AnImage;
        //AnImage.Free(); //error
      end;
  end;

procedure TForm11.Button1Click( Sender : TObject );
  begin
    Image2.Picture.Assign( Effect( Image1.Picture ) );
  end;
```

As I am creating an object, when does one free the created object. I cannot call TPngImage.Free() in the the function as that destroys the object before assignment. So how do I free the object created? Does TPngImage call its destructor when the object goes out of scope? Not freeing the object would lead to memory leak as far as I can see.

Comment: With manual memory management, like in Delphi, it is usually best not to *return* and object at all. *Pass* an object of which you manage the lifetime and let the routine simply use that object. Nothing will be freed automatically, unless your platform uses ARC.

Comment: `Result := AnImage` -> Result is assigned the reference AnImage holds. Both becomes a reference to the same png image object. `AnImage.Free` -> frees that object. Effectively it is equivalent to writing `Result.Free`.

Comment: @rudy Not necessarily. There are many scenarios where returning a newly created instance is the right solution.

Comment: There are two errors here. First you leak. That's easy to solve. Destroy the object once you have finished with it. The other is that the Effect function does not always assign to the return value.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I should try TPictureHelper = class helper for TPicture

Comment: A TPictureHelper could help the TPicture but it won't help you understand the issue here. I suggest you to read the comments to the question.

Comment: Throwing random syntax at the problem won't help you understand it

Comment: The way you have this designed will not work the way you expect. You will need to make sure you free it outside of that function. I don't see a reason why you should preserve the original image, especially since you're ultimately discarding it anyway once you assign to the image control. I would drop the idea of returning a copy, and make it a procedure passing the object and perform the effect directly to it.

Comment: After clicking TForm11.Button1Click with AutoClick 2 every 100 milliseconds well there is no merory leak according to Task Manager. So it seems that TPngImage does indeed  Destroy after going out of scope. 720 * 720 * 32 = 16588800 bytes for every TPngImage.Create() without calling Free() would surely make a dent in system memory. Many thanks my friends.

Comment: @GrooverMD, Windows's TaskManager doesn't show *real* memory consumption by your application. Use special tools for this. F.e. `FastMM` (among free tools for such purposes).

Comment: I do have IoBits Performance monitor as well, same outcome, no decernable increase is memory usage.

Comment: I keep on clickin and nothings stickin.

Comment: Do you want to understand this, or do you just want to use trial and error and fail to understand? It's perfectly possible to understand this. As we have said, you leak the object returned by the function. Why can't you use it, and then destroy it.

Comment: You need to use the proper tools. Just looking at memory usage, no matter what tool, is not what you need. What you need is something *inside* your code to track memory leaks. Built-in to Delphi, there's `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;` on app startup. When you close it, it will tell you how much has leaked. Your code is guaranteed to leak memory.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has several bugs in it:

> ```
> if( Value.Graphic is TPngImage ) then
> ```

If the caller's `TPicture` does not already contain a `TPNGImage`, you don't return anything at all. The `Result` is undefined.

In fact, you shouldn't check the `Graphic`'s type at all.  Various `TGraphic` classes can be assigned to each other, converting their image data from one format to another, so you should let that conversion happen when possible.

> ```
> AnImage.Assign( TPngImage( Value ) );
> ```

You are typecasting the `TPicture` itself. You need to typecast its `Graphic` instead.

> ```
> Result := AnImage;
> //AnImage.Free();
> ```

This requires the caller to take ownership of the `TPNGImage` and free it, which is generally a bad design.

> ```
> Image2.Picture.Assign( Effect( Image1.Picture ) );
> ```

Case in point, the caller is not taking ownership of the returned `TPngImage`, so it is leaked.

If you want to return a new `TPNGImage`, try this instead:

```
function Effect(Value : TPicture) : TPngImage;
begin
  Result := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    if (Value.Graphic <> nil) and (not Value.Graphic.Empty) then
    begin
      Result.Assign(Value.Graphic);
      //Apply effect
    end;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Or

```
function Effect(Value : TPicture) : TPngImage;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Value.Graphic <> nil) and (not Value.Graphic.Empty) then
  begin
    Result := TPngImage.Create;
    try
      Result.Assign(Value.Graphic);
      //Apply effect
    except
      Result.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Either way, you can then do this:

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender : TObject);
var
  AImage: TPngImage;
begin
  AImage := Effect(Image1.Picture);
  try
    Image2.Picture.Assign(AImage);
  finally
    AImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, a better design is to not return a new `TPngImage` at all. Pass in the 2 `TPicture` objects and let `Effect()` manipulate them as needed:

```
procedure Effect(Input, Output : TPicture);
var
  AnImage : TPngImage;
begin
  AnImage := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    if (Input.Graphic <> nil) and (not Input.Graphic.Empty) then
    begin
      AnImage.Assign(Input.Graphic);
      //Apply effect
    end;
    Output.Assign(AnImage);
  finally
    AnImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or

```
procedure Effect(Input, Output : TPicture);
var
  AnImage : TPngImage;
begin
  if (Input.Graphic <> nil) and (not Input.Graphic.Empty) then
  begin
    AnImage := TPngImage.Create.Create;
    try
      AnImage.Assign(Input.Graphic);
      //Apply effect
      Output.Assign(AnImage);
    finally
      AnImage.Free;
    end;
  end else
    Output.Assign(nil);
end;
```

Then you can do this:

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender : TObject);
begin
  Effect(Image1.Picture, Image2.Picture);
end;
```

Comment: That is why you are Remy Lebeau. I thank you for this answer. You help people with programming issues not down them. Unlike various Software Engineers like David who think we are as smart as he is.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this, you are leaking.

You can return an object from a function like this, but after use (in this case, after you assigned it to `Image2.Picture`, you must `Free` it. *But you can only do that if you have a reference to it*. So do this:

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  EffectImage: TPngImage;
begin
  EffectImage := Effect(Image1.Picture);
  Image2.Picture.Assign(EffectImage);
  EffectImage.Free;
end;
```

**Note that if the image is not PNG, your `Effect` function will not return anything valid. That is an issue you have to address too.**

Alternatively, I would do something like this:

```
procedure ProcEffect(InPicture, OutPicture: TPicture);
var
  AnImage : TPngImage;
begin
  if InPicture.Graphic is TPngImage then
  begin
    AnImage := TPngImage.Create;
    try
      AnImage.Assign(InPicture);
      //Apply effect
      OutPicture.Graphic := AnImage; // same as OutPicture.Assign(AnImage);
    finally
      AnImage.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And then call it with:

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProcEffect(Image1.Picture, Image2.Picture);
end;
```